# Managed C++ prospects

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Has anyone tried coding in managed C++? I have a few questions :

1. How productive is the language compared to C#?
2. Is there any restriction on type of projects that can be written? Can we write a web application in managed C++?
3. Is it possible to mix managed and unmanaged C++ code in one application?
4. Is MFC still valid in managed C++? Will it be the best option when considering migration of a VC++ application?

Comment: Just as clarification:  "Managed C++" (really called "Managed Extensions for C++") is old skool and deprecated.  The modern extension to C++ for managed code is called "C++/CLI."

Comment: I assume all of you here mean "C++/CLI", not "Managed C++", right? Managed C++ was so horribly hard to use. C++/CLI made it much much better. (Although as some answers point out, still not perfect.)

Comment: The *only reason* to be using C++/CLI (which is the current name of what used to be "Managed C++") is to provide a bridge between C#/.NET and native C++ code. There is *no good reason* that you'd want to use C++/CLI to do anything else, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found C# to be far more productive. The real magic of managed C++ is that yes, you *can* mix managed and unmanaged code in it - even inside one function! I don't know how Microsoft did that (and apparently neither do they, because the official name for this feature is "IJW" - "it just works" :)).

Comment: Just to supplement our point, in C# you can also mixed managed and unmanaged code inside the same function.  It is a feature of the framework.

Comment: How do you do that in C#? You can use P/Invoke, of course, but you cannot *just write the code*, as if it were a native program, as you can in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2):

I've used managed C++ (C++/CLI) as a bridge between C# and C++.  We had a graphical application that used OpenSceneGraph as the 'bottom' layer.  Managed C++ was then used in between to grab some of the graphical data as well as interface between the C# and the OSG layers.

It worked pretty darn well in that particular application.  However, I would prefer straight C#.

Answer (score 1):

I think C# is far better to work with in a managed environment.  Managed C++ just seems kind of kludgey to me and I'd much rather work with a language that is meant for a managed environment (not that managed c++ won't work).  Furthermore, if you need to, you can call unmanaged code from C# just as you can from managed C++.